# Using While True loops

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements, words

I am supposed to write a code that checks a word for certain syllables (examples: *in*, *ex*, *are*). If the word is made up of only those syllables, the code returns "*Yes*" and "*No*" otherwise (if the word also contains other syllables). The assignment requires me to use a `while true` loop, and while I came up with a simpler way to make this code work, I don't quite know where to start in making a `while true` loop for this problem.

My current code only works for words that *have* all the syllables:

```
def check(word):
    pos = 0
    while True:
        if pos < len(word):
            if word[pos:pos+2] == "in":
                pos += 2 
                break
            if word[pos:pos+2] == "ex":
                pos += 2
                break
            if word[pos:pos+3] == "are":
                pos += 3 
                break
    return "YES"
```

Comment: show us the code you've done

Comment: `while True: pass`. Run then wait (don't do this :))

Comment: using `any` or `all` is way better than `while True: ... break`

Comment: Is your problem thinking about an algorithm, or you already have an algorithm you think should work and only need help writing the code? This is unclear from the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're determined to use a while loop for some reason, it'd be something like this:

```
i = 0

while True:

    i += 1
    word = words[i]

    if (syllables in word):
        print('Syllables are in word')
    else:
        print('Syllables not in word')

    if i > len(words):
        break
```

However, this is probably a much worse way to do solve the issue. When iterating through a set it's often more efficient to use a `for` loop to prevent needless checking of whether the entire set has been checked. A for loop implementation might look like this:

```
for s in syllable_set_1:
    if s in word:
        print('Syllable ' + s + ' is in word')
    else:
        print('Syllable ' + s + ' is not in word')
```

Answer (score 0):

For overlapping syllables you might actually require some kind of backtracking. A simple solution could use while ... else, like this:

```
syllables = ["in", "ex"]
word = "exinex"
while word:
    matches = [s for s in syllables if word.startswith(s)]
    if not matches:
        print "unable to find syllable for " + word
        break
    word = word.replace(matches[0], "", 1)
else:
    print "only expected syllables found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having your actual code, while True-Loops can be used to continue asking for user input until a special "stop word" has been entered.

```
while True:
    text = input("Enter next word to check, end to exit")
    if text=="end":
        break
    else:
        #... your syllable checking
```

This would allow the user to enter several words to check without having to restart the program every time.

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like

```
words = iter(words)
while True:
    try:
        if next(words) in allowed_words:
            continue
        else:
            return 'Yes'
    except StopIteration:
        return 'No'
```

Comment: `return` without a function eh

Comment: Ok, I said *something like* this. The  OP seems to understand the problem well enough to adapt it

Comment: Why is there a try:except needed out of interest?

Comment: When the iterator runs out of words, it throws a `StopIteration` exception. So, you know you have checked all the words, and you must return